# How to change username using mvc4 and simplemembership

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

Why is it that you can't change a simplemembership username. I've tried

```
MembershipUser memUser = Membership.GetUser(existingUser);
memUser.UserName = model.UserName;
Membership.UpdateUser(memUser);
```

I get that MembershipUser.UserName is read only. There are no other available methods for changing the username.

Is there a way around this problem?

Edit: New problem.
When the line

```
 var confirmationToken = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, Request["Password"], new { NameFirst = model.NameFirst, NameLast = model.NameLast, ContactId = newContact.ContactId },true);
```

is run, I get a MembershipCreateUserException and says the username is already in use (it really isn't). It manages to add the user to my UserSecurity table(UserProfile) but doesn't add it to the membership table.
It's attempting to add the user in the webpages_Membership table and not the UserMembership table I created.

Comment: I voted for this to be re-opened because the question is in the context of `SimpleMembership` instead of just `Membership`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be able to edit the users name with the MembershipProvider.
In SimpleMembership you have to add a UserProfile table to your Model, where the username is stored.

You specify the table on initialization:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DBname", "UserProfileTable", "IdColumn", "UsernameColumn", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Comment: I think you can also use it, create the tables of the SimpleMembership at your own and then use the initializer with  autoCreateTables: false  - but you have to use the same table, as the simpleMembership provider would create automatically

Comment: So would creating just the UserProfile table be enough or must I recreate all the simplemembership tables? I'm not sure if I need to do anything different for the table that stores passwords by hashing it.

Comment: check out these articles too:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx
http://blog.osbornm.com/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages/

Comment: you have to create at least webpages_Membership table and the UserProfile table, which can have a different name

Comment: it also depends on what you need - if you need roles too, you have to create more

Comment: Your question about hashing: 
Hashing is be done by the simple membership itself and the hash is stored in the webpages_Membership as string (hashed and salted by System.Web.Helpers.Crypto.HashPassword)
HashPassword is doing it by RFC 2898

Comment: Simplemembership is just a scam to get us using yet another technology. The old one already has the tables you need and works perfectly.

Comment: I'm already too deep into simplemembership. I'm nearly done working with it for this project so I'll stick with it.

Comment: Hey kapsi. I ran into a problem. I created the tables with different names and it manages to create a new user the lin eWEbSecurity.CreateUserandAccount creates the user and throws a user already exists error every single time. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your problem - you may provide more information or code ...

Comment: I've added the code to my question

Comment: You have to use the webpages_Membership table - otherwise it won't work